# Getting Package Qty on Shipping Methods template (answered)

Tags: shipping, quote

I want to get the number of "shippable" products in the quote/basket on the template file `checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml`. The aim is to tell the customer at that point how many more products they would need to buy to qualify for free shipping.

When building shipping method modules, you can get this with `$request->getPackageQty()`;

For example, if you have 3 books, 2 T-shirts and 1 virtual product in your basket, `getPackageQty` will return 5, not 6.

On `checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml`, I've tried the following:

```
$quote = $this->getQuote();
// AND/OR
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();

$packageQty = $quote->getPackageQty();
```

Neither is working. I'm working a bit blind here, can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Sales/Mage_Sales_Model_Quote.html

Turns out you can do:

```
$packageQty = $quote->getItemsSummaryQty() - $quote->getItemVirtualQty();
```

This is the total number of items in the quote, minus the number of unshippable/virtual items, which is a roundabout way of getting what I want.

(will accept answer when I can, in 2 days)